# PHPmailer - failing to send if variable $file1 for attachment does not have a value

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have an HTML form that passes indexes to another form, which creates the necessary variables which are then inserted into PHPMailer. One of the options is to browse to a file which is then attached to the email.
The problem that I am having is that if there is no file to attach, (then the $file1 variable has "no value") PHPMailer returns the eoor that the message cannot be sent as below - pointing to the directory where the files are stored.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: Could not access file:C:/wamp64/www/CIA/PODS/

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
//Server settings
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mail.smtp2go.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'xxx@xx-xxxxxx.co.za';              // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxx';                         // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 2525;                                    // TCP port to connect to
//Recipients
$mail->AllowEmpty = true;
$mail->setFrom('admin@ic-express.co.za', 'ICExpress Waybill Updates');
$mail->addAddress('xxxx@xx.co.za'); 
$mail->addAddress($email);  
$mail->addReplyTo('xxxx@xx.co.za');
$mail->addCC($addemail);
$mail->addCC($addemail2);

echo $file1;
$path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/CIA/PODS/'.$file1;
$name=$file1;
$mail->AddAttachment($path,$name,$encoding ='base64',$type = 'application/octet-stream');
$mail->AllowEmpty = true;
$mail->isHTML(true);                      // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = $subject ;
$mail->Body    = <<<END
```

Comment: in that case you can check the $file variable for blank and then you can ignore the  $mail->AddAttachment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add the attachment if it is available. In case there is no file attachment don't try to add the attachment:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/CIA/PODS/'.$file1;

if (is_dir($path) === false && file_exists($path)) {
    $name = $file1;
    $mail->AddAttachment($path, $name, $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/octet-stream');
}
```

---

As IncredibleHat also mentioned in the comments you can also use the condition `is_file($path)` to check the file path like [PHPMailer itself](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/bbdfa96b95a942ca07dc9e97dd2f2901c17b08d2/src/PHPMailer.php#L2776):

```
if (is_file($path)) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($path, '', $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/octet-stream');
}
```

You also don't need to specify the `name` if you want to use the same as specified on path. PHPMailer is using [the `basename` of the path](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/bbdfa96b95a942ca07dc9e97dd2f2901c17b08d2/src/PHPMailer.php#L2785) if `name` parameter is a empty string.

Comment: Or `is_file($path)` ... which is what PHPMailer is doing to cause the error. One way or the other.